# Bootstrap Tooltip does not get destroyed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code setup for tooltip:

```
<div class="myClass" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
data-delay='{"show":"500"}' rel="tooltip" title="My Text"> <a 
id="myId" target="_blank" 
href="#"><img class="anotherClass" src="somelogo.png" />
<div class="viewText">View</div></a>
</div>
```

When I click on this div, I will get redirected to another page (target="_blank"),but when I come back to my page,the tooltip is just there(may be because the hover event for the tooltip is still there..I suppose..) and does not get destroyed until I manually click somewhere on my page!

I want the tooltip to go away on and only show once the user hovers again.How would I achieve this? Pls help.
I am using Bootstrap 3, Javascript, Jquery 1.10 and CSS3.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a default functionality in bootstrap.min.js

```
c.VERSION = "3.3.7", c.TRANSITION_DURATION = 150, c.DEFAULTS = {
    animation: !0,
    placement: "top",
    selector: !1,
    template: '<div class="tooltip" role="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div>',
    trigger: "hover focus",
    title: "",
    delay: 0,
    html: !1,
    container: !1,
    viewport: {
        selector: "body",
        padding: 0
    }
}
```

Remove "focus" from trigger: "hover focus"

This solved the issue for me.

Comment: I did not find focus property for trigger in my bootstrap.min.js file! Only trigger:"hover" is there

Comment: this worked for me. My previous comment was wrong. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    trigger : 'hover'
});
```

This solved the issue for me.

Comment: This is also technically correct only but it did not work for me, hence did not mark it correct. Thanks for your solution though @mabhijit95a10